# Playwright chromium.launch args not working

Tags: google-chrome, webassembly, playwright

I launch my playwright browser like this:

```
import { chromium } from 'playwright'

async function run() {
    let browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: false, args: ['--experimental-wasm-multi-memory'] });
    let page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://playgameoflife.com')
}
run()
```

Unfortunately the argument seems to not get applied to the browser instance. The browser console shows:

```
Uncaught (in promise) CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): At most one memory is supported (declared 1, imported 1); pass --experimental-wasm-multi-memory to allow more memories @+67
```

(If you  try to run my code snippet from above you will not see the same error in the console, because I actually run an instrumented version of the Website)

What is wrong here?